# Post text and URLs with TwitterKit 2.7 iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I just upgrade TwitterKit in my APP to 2.7 and could not post a tweet like before. Instead, I got an error after calling method *sendTwitterRequest:completion:*

***"Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=32 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Could not authenticate you. (code 32), TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=401, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}"***

I did some research but got no luck. However, I accidentally found out that if I delete the ">>" in my "status" content string, everything is fine! Anyone has a clue why this happened? What if I need insert ">" in my tweet? Any clues would be appreciated!

```
NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @"My tweet >> https://www.google.com"};
NSError *updateRequestError = nil;
NSURLRequest *updateRequest = [myAPIClient URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" parameters:message error:&updateRequestError];
if (updateRequestError) {
    return;
}
[myAPIClient sendTwitterRequest:updateRequest completion:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* updateConnectionError){
    if (!updateConnectionError) {

    } else {
       NSLog(@"error = %@", updateRequestError");
    }
}];
```

Comment: Have you tried HTML-encoding the contents of the status? This could just be the Twitter API seeing the ”>“ as part of a tag and blocking it. I vaguely remember some omissions in Twitter‘s API docs what is supposed to be HTML and what plain text.

Comment: Yes, I did. However, the ">" will still be encoded if I check my tweet from twitter.com. This seems to be a bug in their SDK: https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweets-error/73153/11. Anyway, thanks a lot!